# PHP PDO - Cache data from query, if new rows exist then add to cache

Tags: php, mysql, caching, pdo

On the highest level, I am wondering if such a process is possible - or does it even make much of a difference.

If I query lets say 1500 rows and process the data from these. The user is browsing through the data and after about 10 minutes, there is ~10 new rows.

Is it possible to lets say 'cache' the initial queried and processed data instead of re-querying and re-processing all the old data, in order to show the new data.

At the moment, I query and process the data on each page view. I don't like it, it doesn't feel right.

Not really sure how to go about it. Thanks for any help. Have searched a bit now for caching data, but can't find a similar question/answer for this.

Thanks!

---

Some additional information

Each record queried has a timestamp associated with it in milliseconds. My idea would be that I can store the last record's timestamp, and do a query on the database to see if there is any new records since the last timestamp.

If there is, process just the new records, and add them to the already processed data. This must be a possibility surely, or it surely must be a more efficient way than processing *all* the data again and again.

Thanks!